# Optimizing database for SEO friendly URLs

Tags: database, indexing, seo

I am re-asking a question I wrote before the censors closed my question. (I still don't understand why) https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/.

I want to know how to efficiently query a database according to a non-primary key, such as URLs that have no IDs and just a title.

How would this work in terms of indexing?

The original question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006232/efficiently-accessing-database-without-id).

Comment: An URL is a primary key

Answer (score 1):

You'd still need a candidate key (otherwise, to which database record(s) does a URL refer to?). In terms of indexing, a unique index should be fine to look up URL fragments against it.

Comment: it seems I don't understand indexing enough. do you know any tutorials how to implement this? preferably in asp.net/sql

Comment: It's difficult to be specific without seeing what you've tried already, but if you haven't got anything yet, it might be worth starting out with an MVC framework, which supports [this sort of thing](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/aspnet-mvc-controllers-overview-cs) - just consider a Route that has strings instead of integers, and then it is for the controller to look that up in the database.